# Can I map the number of search matches to a key?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, highlight, functions, repeated-commands

I'd like to map `0` to whatever number of matches I currently have. For example:

[image]

This here has 5 matches. If I wanted to perform a macro on every instance, i'd like to be able to simply type:

`0Q` (`Q` is remapped as execute macro.)

which would be interpreted as:

`5Q`

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the global command to search for the pattern and then execute a command on the available pattern as such

```
:global/pattern/command
```

which could be modified in your case as:

```
:global/pattern/normal @Q
```

where pattern is the word on which you will run the macro and @Q is the macro register.

Comment: And you could omit the pattern: `:global//normal @Q` if you wanted to use the last search.